# Rails: iterating over all objects of a type without loading them all at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Car << ActiveRecord::Base
end

Car.all.each do |car|
  # do stuff
end
```

This loads all the objects of type Car into memory (I think) and iterates through them. What I want instead is to iterate through all the ids and load them one at a time like this:

```
Car.all_ids.each do |id|
  c = Car.find id
  # do stuff
end
```

But all_ids doesn't exist, is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

For Rails 2.3 and up (including Rails 3) the easiest solution is find_each:

```
Car.find_each do |car|
  # do stuff
end
```

This executes the query in batches for you automatically. The default batch size is 1000 but you can set your own. It also works alongside named scopes and ActiveRecord::Relations:

```
Car.hotrods.where(:color => 'red').find_each(:batch_size => 10) { do |car| ... }
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches

Comment: Wonderful.  Can't believe I didn't know about this.

Answer (score 13):

You could use [find_in_batches](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches), which fetches the records `x` at a time, where `x` is configurable and by default 1000.

```
  Person.where("age > 21").find_in_batches do |group|
    # group is an array of 1000 records
    group.each { |person| person.party_all_night! }
  end
```

Comment: Not bad (and upped) but not quite what I'm looking for (and find_in_batches is deprecated).

Comment: @SteveRawlinson: It's not deprecated, it was just moved to the Batches module (the one I linked to you is the updated, nondeprecated version). The old version lives somewhere else and that one is deprecated. I think I know what you want, though, and I don't believe there is a way to do it without dropping down to raw SQL and using a cursor.

Comment: I hope there's also a task to apply `.stop_partying!` after 12 hours 

Answer (score 6):

You could do the following:

```
Car.find(:all, :select => :id).each do |car_id|
  c = Car.find(car_id.id)
end
```

*for Rails 2.3, not familiar with 3 yet*

**Edit**:

One possible solution to be more efficient (less queries):

```
Car.find(:all, :select => :id).map(&:id).each_slice(5) do |ids|
  cars_slice = Car.find(ids)
end
```

Comment: Does what he wants, but is very inefficient because it executes `n` queries.

Comment: Actually, that's great. The large number of queries is no problem, I'm only really concerned with memory.

Comment: This will not work well if you have more than, say, 10 million records. For large data sets, and perhaps to conserve memory, consider using a pagination gem (look up pagination gem in google if unaware), or consider using https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 4+ I find **pluck** very useful.

```
Car.pluck(:id).each do |id|
  c = Car.find id
  # do stuff
end
```

`Car.pluck(:id)` returns an array of entries. You can pluck any other column of your model by changing the parameter. Furthermore, you can pluck a combination of columns. For example:

```
Car.pluck(:id, :make, :model).each do |id, make, model|
  c = Car.find id
  # access make and model as well
end
```

Comment: FYI, `pluck` exists in Rails 3 too